# UWP - Icon Picker

Tags: combobox, uwp, icons

I'm currently learning how to make UWP Apps, and to do so, I'm making an application that allows the user to create notes, categories of notes, etc...

I have a NavigationView in which every category will be listed, and when the user clicks on a specific category, something (I don't know what yet) pops up with a list of all the notes.

I want each category to have an icon, so when the pane of the NavigationView is closed, the user can still click on a category .
**My problem is the following :**

When the user creates a new category, I want to give him the choice of the icon through a combobox (or something acting the same) with all the possible icons in it.

- Is it possible to put icons in a Combobox ?
- How can I get the same icons as those I would use for a NavigationViewItem, to use them as item source for my Combobox ?

**EDIT :**

Here's what I've done : I added an ItemTemplate to my Combobox, using the SymbolIcon component :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="iconpicker">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{Binding symbol}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I also made a simple class :

```
public class ComboSymbol
{
    public Symbol symbol;
}
```

And here's my code to fill the combobox :

```
ObservableCollection<ComboSymbol> images = new ObservableCollection<ComboSymbol>();
iconpicker.ItemsSource = images;
images.Add(new ComboSymbol { symbol = Symbol.Accept });
```

And.. it's almost working.
[Picture of the combobox item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hTSW.png)

As you can see, the symbol is not the one I choosed. And no matter which symbol I pick (in code-behind), there is always this emoji instead.

**EDIT 2 :**
I was searching where I did something wrong, and apparently it's about my binding. There is a default icon for SymbolIcon component (I just created a SymbolIcon without telling the Symbol I want and this emoji appeared again, so I guess in my case my binding is not good, and because it can't find the Symbol I want, the program used the default icon).

**Final edit :**
Here was the problem : I just forgot to put the "{ get; set; }" after the members declaration in my class. It's now working !

```
public Symbol symbol { get; set; } // Fix
```

Comment: you can prefer that answer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/928a83b5-09ad-4553-9bc3-45c6dd91a419/add-a-image-to-comboboxitem?forum=wpf

Comment: @shubham-sahu thanks ! I'm almost done. I have a class with only one member (the icon as a BitmapImage). I'm trying to convert a Windows.UI.Xaml.Symbol item as a BitmapImage but I don't know how to do it, do you have an idea ?

Comment: @christophechichmanian Please post a [mcve] to show for us what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several UWP controls that can display "icons". Their common parent is an `IconElement` class and it has the following implementations:

- **BitmapIcon** - displays an image (usually .png) as icon
- **PathIcon** - displays a XAML path as icon
- **FontIcon** - displays a string in a given font as icon
- **SymbolIcon** - displays an icon based on a value from predefined set of system symbols

You can certainly use the same icons for `NavigationView` as for `ComboBox` items.

Customizing the `ComboBox` is quite easy with XAML, because it is fully templateable and you can simply create a custom template:

This assumes `Items` is a collection of a custom class which has an `IconUri` property with path to an image used as the icon and a `Text` property with some text. It will then display a two column layout with an icon on the left and text next to it.

Comment: Thanks, SymbolIcon is what I was looking for ! But now I have an other problem (see the main message)